# For an independent sequence of random vectors, $\{X_i\}$, under what conditions is the limit of $\frac{1}{n}\sum_i^n\Sigma_i$ positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

Here $\Sigma_i$ is the covariance matrix of $X_i$.

In general, I know that if, for example $X = (x, y, z)$, then $\Sigma_X$ is positive definite if none of it's coordinate r.v.s can be expressed as an exact linear function of the others.

My question is if I am given $\{X_i\}$ an independent, but not necessarily identically distributed sequence, and suppose I have that, for each $i$, none of $X_i$'s coordinate r.v.s can be expressed as an exact linear function of $X_i$s other coordinate r.v.s, and suppose the limit of $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\Sigma_i$ exists (in probability), is this enough to have that limit be a positive definite matrix?

I realize that the sum of positive definite matrices is positive definite, and so, $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\Sigma_i$ is positive definite for each $n$. Under what conditions does this hold in the limit?

Comment: Oh oops! I have added the sum now, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One first note: the covariance matrix $\Sigma_i$ is a property of the distribution of $X_i$, not of the value. So if the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n \Sigma_i$ exists, there is no "in probability" to it; nothing in this expression is random.

Anyway, it is possible for the limit to exist, but not be positive definite. For example, in two dimensions, let $X_i = (U_i, U_i + \frac1{2_i} V_i)$, where all the $U_i$ and $V_i$ are independent standard Gaussians. Then $$\Sigma_i = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1& 1 + 2^{-i}\end{bmatrix}$$ and the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n \Sigma_i$ will be $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$which is not positive definite.

One sufficient condition that guarantees a positive definite limit is to have each $\Sigma_i - \epsilon I$ be positive definite for some fixed $\epsilon>0$ (independent of $i$).